# PHP-JavaScript security

Tags: javascript, php, security

I am really familiar with JavaScript but I don't really know server-side scripting yet.

Let's say I have a JavaScript game on my server that has a score counter. The score is stored in a variable, and if it's high enough, an option to store it is shown. The score and a user defined name is then sent to the server. A PHP script stores the string to a file.

**Now the problem is:**
What is keeping the users from

(A) Sending a fake score from an external script to the PHP script

(B) Modifying the JavaScript on the page to cheat and get a higher score, or modify the score variable itself?

I don't use `eval()` in any of the scripts. All the PHP files are accessible for everyone, and all of them use POST.

Answer (score 0):

The server must have the possibility to validate the highscore, so you have to send **every change of state** in the game to the server with Javascript.

Every step you validate within Javascript, must also be validated by PHP.

Example:

Player moves 2 steps to the right within 3 seconds.
Send every step as an action to the server.
Validate: player is ABLE to move a maximum amout of steps within X seconds.
Server always knows the position of the player. If you fake a step, lets say from position 1/1 to 10/1 within 1 request, the server answers: "cheat detected, cannot fly!".

Or lets say the server knows your position is 5/5. The player cheats: "Move from 3/3 to 10/10". Server knows: wrong starting position + too much steps within available movement area.

It's like maths, JS sends "3+3 = 8", PHP says: false, 3+3 = 6, client cheating